# Is there an R function to calculate the Total Probability, once I get a Beta Posterior, after beginning with an initial Beta Prior in R

Tags: r, bayesian

I started with a uniform Prior of Beta [1,1] to model a probability Theta.  P(Theta)

I used the Beta Binomial conjugacy approach, and got a posterior Beta [3,1]. P(Theta|X)

This is because ( I got 3 success in 3 trials).

Now I know I can visualize this Beta[3,1] as a PDF and draw information from it.(such as credible interval of Theta).

However, What I am interested in , is the Total Probability given the Theta.(Denominator of Bayes rule) . P(X)

I am not that good in integration. So is there some function in R, which will, calculate the Total Probability, using my new Posterior Beta prior. So that I can get a predictive interval.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the code below is for your purpose

```
p <- function(x) x**3*dbeta(x,1,1)/dbeta(x,3,1)
px <- function(x) p(x)/(integrate(p,0,1)$value)
```

Comment: It seems real close to what I am looking for. I might need to implement it to see, what happens in R

Comment: I was able to come up with  some code to get what I wanted done. Unfortunately it is super long and I was a bit busy to update the answer. With clear explanations. I will put it up for others soon.

As for your answer. Now that I know how to validate my solution. I will have to run the numbers through your code. If both our approaches get the same answer. Then I can confirm 
It works. Thanks for the reminder I will get it done before this week ends.

Comment: Hi! You don't need no function to calculate total probabilty. In bayesian inference the denominator you are looking for its just a normalizing constant (that's why we generally refer to the posterior probability using simply the popto operator) in your case as you're using a conjugate scheme the normalizing constant is given by your kernel.